# Network path in BUILD_PATH in .env file is breaking npm start localhost:3000

Tags: reactjs, node.js, environment-variables

My department gave me a public_html folder on a network which will host my personal website, so if I throw an index.html file in there, it will function.

I am working on building a react page. I used the standard `npx create-react-app` to build my app and when I execute: `npm start` it pulls up a browser window with `localhost:3000`, and everything is fine.

I can simply execute `npm run build` which creates a build folder, and I can copy and paste the contents of the build folder into the `public_html` folder and the website works great.

I would like to set it up so that npm run build builds directly into the `public_html` folder, so I used the .env file and added the path (see image below):

[Screenshot of .env file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVEFd.png)

When I execute `npm run build`, everything works perfectly. The contents are built to the correct path. However, after adding that line to the .env folder, suddenly `npm start` no longer works. It loads a browser window with `localhost:3000`, but it continues loading forever.

According to the documentation, BUILD_PATH should be ignored by the development side, but that does not seem to be the case.

Troubleshooting steps:
Changing the BUILD_PATH to a non-network path, which leads to `npm start` working correctly again
Commented out the BUILD_PATH, which leads to `npm start` working correctly again
Looked through: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/ to see if anything might fix the issue, but didn't see anything promising.
I did try to add `PORT=3000` and `PORT=5000` to see if hardcoding the default port or changing the port would do anything, which it didn't.

Summary of what I did and what I expected:
I tried to add a network path to BUILD_PATH.

I was expecting npm run build to build to the network path, which it did.
However, this led to npm start no longer working (persistent loading)